# Hovering a div when on datatables header cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I currently have a filtering div:

```
<div class="filterOptions" id="FilterStatus">
<input type="checkbox" id="Status1" data-status="1"><label for="Status1">1</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="Status2" data-status="2"><label for="Status2">2</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="Status3" data-status="3"><label for="Status3">3</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="Status4" data-status="4"><label for="Status4">4</label>
</div>
```

Which with it's own bit of javascript is doing the job perfectly. However I'd like to position this just below the "Status" column header when the header is hovered. Placing the code in the table itself seems to delete the code, so is there somewhere else I should be adding it?

This [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pkbhpLtf/) shows kind of what is happening. On this it shows the div although it moves it out of the table div. Ideally I want it to only show on hover of the specific table header but i'm stumped.

Comment: Would you mind to create a fiddle to showcase problem or issue you are facing?

Comment: I'll have a go... I'm not really sure it's an issue, more that when datatables is running it is just ignoring my custom div totally! Will see if I can recreate it.

Comment: @VilasKumkar have added a jsFiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/pkbhpLtf/9/):

```
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable({
    autoWidth: false,
    initComplete: function(settings, json) {
        let api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api(settings);
        let header = api.column(0).header();
        let originalText = $(header).text();
        let newText = originalText + `<div class="filterOptions" id="FilterStatus">
                <input type="checkbox" id="Status1" data-status="1">
                <label for="Status1">1</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="Status2" data-status="2">
                <label for="Status2">2</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="Status3" data-status="3">
                <label for="Status3">3</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="Status4" data-status="4">
                <label for="Status4">4</label>
            </div>`;
        $(header).html(newText).attr("id", "hover")
    }
});
```

With this CSS:

```
#FilterStatus {
    display: none;
}

#hover:hover #FilterStatus {
    display: block;
}
```

You'll need to alter the action of your check-boxes though!

Comment: This is almost spot on, and have added some styles to make the div absolute positioned so it doesn't affect the header... Only issue is that when you click anywhere in the popup, it counts it as a click on the header, meaning it re-orders by that column.

Comment: See here for how clicking the absolute div still adjusts the parent https://jsfiddle.net/pkbhpLtf/12/

Comment: Have now got a workaround for it using `stopPropagation();`

Answer (score 1):

Well one approach is placing a second `<tr>` under the `<thead>` and adding a `hover` event with jQuery like so:

```js
$('.status-header').hover(function(){
  $('.filterOptions').css('display','inline');
}, function(){
  $('.filterOptions').css('display','none');
})

var table = $('#myTable').DataTable({autoWidth: false});
```

```css
.filterOptions {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table id="myTable" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="status-header">Status

            </th>

            <th>Col 1</th>
            <th>Col 2</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="status-header">
            <td colspan="3" class="">
                <div class="filterOptions" id="FilterStatus">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="Status1" data-status="1"><label for="Status1">1</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="Status2" data-status="2"><label for="Status2">2</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="Status3" data-status="3"><label for="Status3">3</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="Status4" data-status="4"><label for="Status4">4</label>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Status 1</td>
            <td>Row 1 Data</td>
            <td>Row 1 Data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Status 2</td>
            <td>Row 2 Data</td>
            <td>Row 2 Data</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This messes up the sorting of the tables bud, I already tried it.

Comment: @BN83 When I click on Status it still sorts correctly.. Did you check what I did?

Comment: Ah, that is working now, potentially in the last edit you made? Unfortunately I don't want the extra table. @annoyingmouse's answer is nearly ideal for what I'm trying to do though. But thank you for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this : Using CSS

Note: You need to take care before using this snippet, as datatable sort itself on click of "th" tag, using some CSS I've managed to overcome from that issue but it's not 100% fixed.

```js
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable({autoWidth: false});
```

```css
ul {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
ul li {
 position: relative;
}
ul li ul {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 top: 100%;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
 color: #fff;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 10px;
}
ul li:hover ul {
 display: block;
}
ul li li {
 display: block;
 clear: both;
 
}
ul li ul input[type="checkbox"] {
 cursor: not-allowed;
 display: block;
 float: left;
 margin: 5px 10px 0 0;
}

ul li ul label {
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
 display: block;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table id="myTable" class="display">
   <thead>
    <tr>
          <th>
      <ul>
       <li>
        <a href="#">Status</a>
        <ul>
         <li><label for="Status1"><input type="checkbox" id="Status1" data-status="1">1</label></li>
         <li><label for="Status2"><input type="checkbox" id="Status2" data-status="2">2</label></li>
         <li><label for="Status3"><input type="checkbox" id="Status3" data-status="3">3</label></li>
         <li><label for="Status4"><input type="checkbox" id="Status4" data-status="4">4</label></li>
        </ul>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </th>
     <th>Col 1</th>
     <th>Col 2</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
          <td>Status 1</td>
     <td>Row 1 Data</td>
     <td>Row 1 Data</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Status 2</td>
     <td>Row 2 Data</td>
     <td>Row 2 Data</td>
    </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```